# Button ActionListener error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I need help with this problem. The error message on BlueJ says "cannot find symbol - variable SevenContinentsFrame. I'm a beginner and how no idea what to do whatsoever and has been working on this code for hours.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    public class SevenContinents  extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");

       public SevenContinents()
        {

             //BUTTONS!!!

            setSize(1500,1000);

            button1.addActionListener(this);
            button2.addActionListener(this);
            button3.addActionListener(this);
            button4.addActionListener(this);
            button5.addActionListener(this);
            button6.addActionListener(this);
            button7.addActionListener(this);

            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button1);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button2);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button3);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button4);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button5);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button6);
            SevenContinentsFrame.add(button7);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource == btn1)
           {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn2)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn3)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn4)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn5)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn6)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(e.getSource == btn7)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            JFrame SevenContinentsFrame = new JFrame();
            SevenContinentsFrame.setVisible(true);
            SevenContinentsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 JFrame SevenContinentsFrame = new JFrame();
```

You're creating a `JFrame` from the Swing API, not an instance of `SevenContients`, which is also a `JFrame`.

```
SevenContinents SevenContinentsFrame = new SevenContinents();
```

And this...

```
SevenContinentsFrame.add(button1);
```

You're referencing a name that doesn't exist. You've created a variable with that name in the main method, but it's not visible in the `SevenContinents` constructor. Simply remove the name. E.g.

```
add(button1);
add(button2);
.
.
.
```

You also need to add `()` to `getSource`, use the correct variable names for the buttons referenced in your action listener, and change the layout so the buttons show.

**Corrected Code**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class SevenContinents extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");

    public SevenContinents()
    {

        //BUTTONS!!!
        setSize(1500, 1000);

        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        button5.addActionListener(this);
        button6.addActionListener(this);
        button7.addActionListener(this);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(button1);
        add(button2);
        add(button3);
        add(button4);
        add(button5);
        add(button6);
        add(button7);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button3) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button4) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button5) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button6) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button7) {
            System.out.println("You chose...");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SevenContinents SevenContinentsFrame = new SevenContinents();
        SevenContinentsFrame.setVisible(true);
        SevenContinentsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class' name is `SevenContinents` and you are trying to access `SevenContinentsFrame`, which doesn't exists. Change all references to `SevenContinentsFrame` with `SevenContinents` and viola!

Answer (score 0):

this is your full code try this it is tested and it is better if you used any other IDE than BlueJ changes are made in this lines

it is not JFrame it's your class name

```
  JFrame SevenContinentsFrame = new JFrame();
```

and what is this

```
SevenContinentsFrame.add(button1);
```

also you did not add a container and it is better if you used array for your buttons 
the code for the container

```
Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(pane);
```

and final thing i removed your implement and replace it with and i added all the button to a panel

```
        package answer;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SevenContinents  extends JFrame 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SevenContinents SevenContinentsFrame = new SevenContinents();
            SevenContinentsFrame.setVisible(true);

        }

        JButton button1;  
        JButton button2;  
        JButton button3;  
        JButton button4;  
        JButton button5;  
        JButton button6; 
        JButton button7; 

       public SevenContinents()
        {

             //BUTTONS!!!

            setSize(500,500);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(SevenContinents.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            button1 = new JButton("1");
            button2 = new JButton("2");
            button3 = new JButton("3");
            button4 = new JButton("4");
            button5 = new JButton("5");
            button6 = new JButton("6");
            button7 = new JButton("7");






            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.add(button1);
            pane.add(button2);
            pane.add(button3);
            pane.add(button4);
            pane.add(button5);
            pane.add(button6);
            pane.add(button7);

            Container cp = getContentPane();
            cp.add(pane);


            button1.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button2.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button3.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button4.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button5.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button6.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());
            button7.addActionListener(new addButtonWatcher());

        }


private class addButtonWatcher implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
        {
            Object buttonPressed= a.getSource();
            if(buttonPressed.equals(button1))
           {

            }
            if(buttonPressed.equals(button2))
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(buttonPressed.equals(button3))
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(buttonPressed == button4)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(buttonPressed == button5)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(buttonPressed == button6)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }
            if(buttonPressed == button7)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose...");
            }

        }
}


   }
```

Comment: You should also explain what you changed about the code, and why it works compared to what the user has. _That_ is a more valid answer, and possibly cause for an up-vote, should the answer appear correct.